# How to read an embedded resource using the ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, embedded-resource, csproj

As explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1#manifestembeddedfileprovider) I have:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
   <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**/*.de-CH.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

in my `csproj`. And then I'm trying to read one of these embedded JSONs using:

```
var manifestEmbeddedProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(assembly);
var fileInfo = manifestEmbeddedProvider.GetFileInfo(resourceFile);
// fileInfo.Exists is true here!!!
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileInfo.CreateReadStream())) {
    ....
}
```

But I get a `NullReferenceException` at `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.ManifestFileInfo.CreateReadStream()`.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the embedded resource automatically lands in a satellite assembly because it has a culture name in its filename as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47991149/331281). This seems to lead to the `NullReferenceException` in `CreateReadStream()`. The question remains how to read that resource from the satellite assembly using the `ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider`.

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dradovic/0548310e623391145cfb0c04bd2db772) to play around with.

Comment: Could you find a solution for this problem?